# Can one app call another which then returns a result?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, interop

I know it's possible to launch another app from within an app, using the openURL method. Also it is possible to check with canHandleURL if that app can open that URL.

But is there also a way to call an app and just let it do a calculation and then return the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/) (example how to send a text to the called app)

in your case: let's say you have 2 apps (app1 and app2)
and 2 url schemes (`protocolThatCallsApp1://` and `protocolThatCallsApp2://`)

in your app1, you call app2 using `protocolThatCallsApp2://`
then in your app2 you make your calculations and call app1 using `protocolThatCallsApp1://+yourCalculations` and you make the required parsing to get the result in your app1

Answer (score 2):

The second app should use the same mechanism (`openURL`) to call the first app.

The Facebook sdk uses this method to implement [Single Sign-On](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso):

> If the app is running in a version of iOS that supports multitasking, and if the device has the Facebook app of version 3.2.3 or greater installed, the SDK attempts to open the authorization dialog within the Facebook app. After the user grants or declines the authorization, **the Facebook app redirects back to the calling app**, passing the authorization token, expiration, and any other parameters the Facebook OAuth server may return.

Comment: Is there an example how to implement this? Just call openURL inside openURL and immediately redirect back to the other app?